# How can I process asynchronous results in order as soon as they resolve in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I have an asynchronous function that takes quite a bit of time to call back, that needs to run for an array of inputs, and pipe the results to subsequent operations. My initial approach was Promise-based:

```
Promise.all(entries.map((entry) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    processEntry(entry, resolve);
  });
})).then((outputs) => {
  outputs.forEach((output) => {
    return console.log(output);
  });
  callback();
});
```

The issue with this, is that the outputs only get processed (or in this case logged) after all of them have resolved. In order to have them log as soon as they've resolved, I tried this more old-fashioned approach:

```
var i = 0;
entries.forEach((entry) => {
  processEntry(entry, (output) => {
    console.log(output);
    if (++i >= entries.length)
      callback();
  });
});
```

This works for my very particular case, but doesn't seem like a correct general solution, since there's no longer any guarantee that the outputs will be in order.

The best way I can think of so far to achieve the desired effect, is to populate an array with the outputs at their original index in `entries`, and every time a new output comes, you process the outputs from the start of the array with a separate sliding index that stops when it reaches an `undefined`.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What is `callback()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comments, you want to kick off all the `processEntry` but process them in order

```
entries.map(entry => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    processEntry(entry, resolve);
}))
.reduce((promise, entry) => {
    return promise.then(() => entry)
    .then(value => console.log(value));
}, Promise.resolve())
.then(() => {
    // all done at this point
});
```

If you want a final then with ALL the results

```
entries.map(entry => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    processEntry(entry, resolve);
}))
.reduce((promise, entry) => {
    return promise.then(results => entry.then(value => {
        // process results in order but as soon as possible
        console.log(value)
        // concat to the results
        return results.concat(value);
    }));
}, Promise.resolve([]))
.then(results => {
    // all results in correct order
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that suffer from the same out-of-order issue as my second example? They might not log in their original order.

Comment: How can you have the right order without waiting for all asynchronous tasks to complete? in the Promise.all().then they'll be in the right order, of course

Comment: If the first one completes before the second one, I want to log that while the second one is still processing.

Comment: ahhhh, now I get it - hang on

Comment: That's how I understood it, but I don't think the first one will log in completion order. What if `processEntry` is `(x, cb) => setTimeout(cb, Math.random() * 1000)`?

Comment: `.then(() => entry)` --- what is it supposed to do? Also, I'm sure the assignment `promise = ...` is redundant there.

Comment: sorry, a missing a `return` instead of the `promise =` (was using different technique) - editing

Comment: `what is it supposed to do?` exactly what it looks like it's doing ... promise chaining

Comment: entry is not a function - your move @zerkms

Comment: @JaromandaX oh jeez, what a dumb comment I made above :-D Sorry :)

Comment: no such thing as a dumb comment - though, that's pretty close :D

Comment: Thanks for your persistence @JaromandaX. Using `reduce` here is very sleek, and I believe this solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are use `es6` now, maybe you can try to use `async/await`, you can see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

so your code maybe look like as follow:

```
const processEntry = async (entry) => {
    // ...other code
}

const getFinalResult = async (entries) => {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        const data = await processEntry(entries[i]);
        result.push(data);
    }
    return result
}

const result = await getFinalResult(entries);
```

if you aren't familiar with `async/await`, you can still use `promise`

then you can try it in this way

```
let promise = Promise.resolve();
let result  = [];
for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    ((entry) => {
        promise = promise.then(() => {
            const data = processEntry(entry);
            result.push(result);
        })
    }
    )(entries[i)
}

promise.then(() => {
    callback(result)

})
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that `processEntry` will happen sequentially then. I want them to happen in parallel, and the results to be e.g. logged in order.

Comment: if so, your can try to use `Promise.all`, then sort the log by index.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I'm trying to avoid `Promise.all` because I want to log as they're still processing, and not wait until everything processes before I start logging.